# Using pandas crosstab to compute cross count on a category column

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have a table with customer purchasing product category.
I am trying to build a cross-selling matrix counting the unique customer for each couple of product category, and have a total with unique count as well.

`pandas.crosstab` is a good way to start, but fails on subtotals (i.e. `margins=True`)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cust':  ['1', '1', '2', '3', '3', '4', '5'], # customer ID
    'categ': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']  # category ID
})
# have 2 columns to make the crosstab
dd = pd.merge(df, df, on='cust')
```

Then `pd.crosstab(dd.categ_x, dd.categ_y, margins=True)` gives:

```
| categ_x | a | b | All | 
|---------|---|---|-----| 
| a       | 3 | 2 | 5   | 
| b       | 2 | 4 | 6   | 
| All     | 5 | 6 | 11  |
```

the `pd.merge` helps to populate the cells with the right figures in the crosstable, but lead to bad counting for subtotals/margins

What I would expect is:

```
| categ_x | a | b | All | 
|---------|---|---|-----| 
| a       | 3 | 2 | 3   | -- I have 3 unique clients with 'a'
| b       | 2 | 4 | 4   | -- I have 4 unique clients with 'b'
| All     | 3 | 4 | 5   | -- I have 5 unique clients in total
```

I have try some count, uniques... without much success so far.

**EDIT**

[jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) answer is fine, but I was wondering if their was a way to do it directly through `crosstab`, using the right `aggfunc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this does what I need:

```
pd.crosstab(
    dd.categ_x, dd.categ_y, margins=True, 
    values=dd.cust, aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique
)
```

gives:

```
| categ_x | a | b | All |
|---------|---|---|-----|
| a       | 3 | 2 | 3   |
| b       | 2 | 4 | 4   |
| All     | 3 | 4 | 5   |
```

`pd.Series.nunique` gives the length/size of the unique values of `values` (here `dd.cust`).

Answer (score 1):

You can count values by [`groupby.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and add values manually by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
s = df2.groupby(['categ'])['cust'].nunique().rename('All')
s1 = s.append(pd.Series({'All': df2['cust'].nunique()}, name='All'))

df = pd.crosstab(dd.categ_x, dd.categ_y).join(s).append(s1)
print (df)
         a  b  All
categ_x           
a        3  2    3
b        2  4    4
All      3  4    5
```

Another similar solution:

```
s = df2.groupby(['categ'])['cust'].nunique().rename('All')
df = pd.crosstab(dd.categ_x, dd.categ_y).join(s).append(s)
df.loc['All','All'] = df2['cust'].nunique()
df = df.astype(int)
print (df)
         a  b  All
categ_x           
a        3  2    3
b        2  4    4
All      3  4    5
```

Comment: Thanks this is definitely useful. Iwas just wondering if it can be done in 1 call of `crosstab`